# Call Back In Union All Within the With-As-Table Itself

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[A]
AS
BEGIN
WITH SplitSting1
AS(  
Select id, NameString, emp
  ,LEFT(NameString,CHARINDEX(',',NameString)-1) As Head
  ,RIGHT(NameString,LEN(NameString)-CHARINDEX(',',NameString))  AS Remainder
From [dbo].[Table_1]
WHERE NameString IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',NameString)>0
Union ALL
Select id, NameString, emp
    ,LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)-1)
    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(',',Remainder))      
From SplitSting1
WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',Remainder)>0
)
Select * from SplitSting1 order by id option (maxrecursion 0); 
END
```

[image]

[image]

The first image is the table I query.
The second image is the output I run my stored procedure.

Can anyone assist to explain how the code is running to generate the output seem like split the **NameString/Remainder** Column into **Head** Column. How is the algorithm work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Recursive Common Table Expression` or `Recursive CTE`.

References:
[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for SQL Server
<sup><sub>(they are supported by other databases too)</sub></sup>
[A tutorial](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) and [another one](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/), both from a very quick Google search so you might find better with more effort now you know the right terms to search for.